# htaccess rewrite with a cookie which is equal to a php script that returns a variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have a folder that's located under my root file , I'm trying to restrict access to that folder by using cookies

What I want is to rewrite a redirect based on a cookie value ,

For example in my htaccess I have this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 // check if cookie is set and is equal to script.php
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*)mycookie=[script.php]  [NC] 
 // allow access if above condition is met [ which i cant figure out how to implement]
 RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/folder/index.html [NC,L]
 // or if the conditions above are not met rewrite somewhere else
```

Now here is how I want it work

When user clicks this url.. http://example/contents/folder/index.html , Server should check if the **mycookie** isset and is equal to a variable returned with **script.php** file , then if condition is met let them in or rewrite to another url

The **script.php** returns a variable that is in the database 
This variable is generated every time user signs in and updates a row field in the database to prevent reuse of cookie variable . meaning one wont be able to manipulate cookie by either setting their own variable or copying and reuse them somewhere else .

Everything in the script.php is taken care my problem is with htaccess file . 
Please help

Comment: This is just a weird setup to begin with. You should just redirect the url to script.php which instead of returning the value compares it with mycookie value and redirects accordingly. No point in spilling PHP logic into htaccess!

Comment: Thanks @RaviThapliyal  , So how do I rewrite the above condition to check if script.php returns upon validation and rewrite to another url ..

Comment: I meant do compare and redirect both in PHP. htaccess isn't required here!

Comment: from my imagination - the folder is in my route path , index.html file loads bunch of swf files , I cant output it in browser unless I'm inside the contents folder [ It wont load  a swf movie from outside ]  , so wat Im trying to achieve here is to let url be visible but validates with apache on request

Answer (score 0):

What I'm suggesting in my comments is that your .htaccess would simply intercept and forward the request to the *script.php* file. It's then your script who is responsible for both verifying the cookie as well as what finally gets displayed.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/index\.html$ /folder/script.php [NC,L]
```

Now, in you php, verify the *cookie* and *include* or *redirect* accordingly.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["myCookie"]) && verifyCookie($_COOKIE["myCookie"])) {
        include 'index.html';
    } else {
        header ("Location: http://domain.com/some/other/page.php");
    }
?>
```